# Using attribute resources (?attr/) in layout binding?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-databinding

Data binding in Android currently seems to support the following reference resources (according to [data binding guide](http://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html)): `@array`, `@color`, `@int`, `@dimen`, `@string`... which will give referenced values as arguments in static `@BindingAdapter` method.

For example:

**layout/web_view.xml**

```
<WebView
    app:htmlTextColor="@{@color/colorText}"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

**Bindings.java**

```
@BindingAdapter({"bind:htmlTextColor"})
public static void setHtml(WebView webView, int textColor) {
    // binding logic
}
```

But with [themes and styles](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#PlatformStyles), it's more often that I use an attribute resource, e.g. `?android:attr/textColorPrimary` than a `@color` reference. For such cases, how would the binding `"@{}"` syntax look like? Currently this is how I make it work, but maybe there is a better way?

**layout/web_view.xml**

```
<WebView
    app:htmlTextColor="@{android.R.attr.textColorPrimary}"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

**Bindings.java**

```
@BindingAdapter({"bind:htmlTextColor"})
public static void setHtml(WebView webView, int textColorAttr) {
    // binding logic
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If `@{android.R.attr.textColorPrimary}` resolves to the value of `android.R.attr.textColorPrimary` in Java, all you need to do is resolve that to a color.

There's a bit of a setup going into this.

#### ContextUtils.java

The following method resolves supplied `attr` of `context`'s theme and optional `style` to a color. Falls back to `fallback` color if there's an error.

```
@ColorInt
public static int resolveColor(final Context context, @StyleRes final int style, @AttrRes final int attr, @ColorInt final int fallback) {
    final TypedArray ta = obtainTypedArray(context, style, attr);
    try {
        return ta.getColor(0, fallback);
    } finally {
        ta.recycle()
    }
}

@ColorInt
public static int resolveColor(final Context context, @AttrRes final int attr, @ColorInt final int fallback) {
    return resolveColor(context, 0, attr, fallback);
}
```

Utility methods helping to achieve the above goal efficiently.

```
private static TypedArray obtainTypedArray(final Context context, @StyleRes final int style, @AttrRes final int attr): TypedArray {
    final int[] tempArray = getTempArray();
    tempArray[0] = attr;
    return context.obtainStyledAttributes(style, tempArray);
}

private static final ThreadLocal<int[]> TEMP_ARRAY = new ThreadLocal<>();

private static final int[] getTempArray() {
    int[] tempArray = TEMP_ARRAY.get();
    if (tempArray == null) {
        tempArray = int[1];
        TEMP_ARRAY.set(tempArray);
    }
    return tempArray;
}
```

More complex code available in my `android-commons` library ([here](https://github.com/consp1racy/android-commons/blob/3cd3d5cf7b2bfc1fb5ce9404d3b6fa3670ba9a42/commons-resources/src/main/java/net/xpece/android/content/Resources.kt) and [here](https://github.com/consp1racy/android-commons/blob/3cd3d5cf7b2bfc1fb5ce9404d3b6fa3670ba9a42/commons-base/src/main/java/net/xpece/android/content/BaseResources.kt)).

#### Bindings.java

Here's how to use it:

```
@BindingAdapter({"bind:htmlTextColor"})
public static void setHtml(final WebView webView, @AttrRes final int textColorAttr) {
    final Context context = webView.getContext();
    final int textColor = ContextUtils.resolveColor(context, textColorAttr, Color.BLACK);

    // binding logic
}
```

Comment: The link is out of date. Here is the working one:
https://github.com/consp1racy/android-commons/blob/master/commons-resources/src/main/java/net/xpece/android/content/Resources.kt

Comment: @goemic Thanks for the notice, but don't link to master, it can change at any time. Use a permalink (press Y in Github) like this one: https://github.com/consp1racy/android-commons/blob/3cd3d5cf7b2bfc1fb5ce9404d3b6fa3670ba9a42/commons-resources/src/main/java/net/xpece/android/content/Resources.kt

Answer (score 1):

**Use a BindingAdapter**

A [BindingAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/BindingAdapter.html) lets you manipulate and do a bit more involved logic on your data before applying it to the View. To use a [BindingAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/BindingAdapter.html), first create a static method in your code that is bound to either a standard Android attribute or a custom one.

I create a custom attribute here called characterBackground:

```
@BindingAdapter({"characterBackground"})
public static void characterBackground(TextView textView, AdventureTimeCharacters character) {
     textView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(textView.getContext(), character.getColour()));
}
```

You can then use this BindingAdapter in the TextView:

```
app:characterBackground="@{character}"
```

Do not forget to add the app namespace! Android Studio can add this for you. Just type in appNs and it will autocomplete.

This solution works, but is a bit too involved. And you said data binding is easy..

Answer (score 0):

It appears that themes are currently not supported for use in layout expressions with databinding as is explained by @yigit in the comments for the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31235519/data-binding-with-theme-attributes).